# How to ignore some routes from @UseGuards() in a controller?

Tags: nestjs

I have a controller like this:

```
@ApiBearerAuth()
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
@ApiTags('books')
@Controller('books')
export class BooksController {

  @Post()
  async create(@Body() createBookVm: CreateBookVm) {
    //........
  }

  @Get()
  async all() {
    //........
  }
}
```

When I access `all()` rout in above controller without accessToken I get the foloowing error:

```
{"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized"}
```

It is a correct behavior but I want ignore `all()` action from general `@UseGuards` of the controller. I want access it as a public rout without authorization.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have used the `app.useGlobalGuards()` method inside *main.ts* file, add the following code inside the *auth.guard.ts* file:

```
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AuthGuard as PassportAuthGaurd } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard extends PassportAuthGaurd('jwt') {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {
    super();
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const isPublic = this.reflector.get<boolean>(
      'isPublic',
      context.getHandler()
    );

    if (isPublic) {
      return true;
    }

    return super.canActivate(context);
  }
}
```

I had used pssport jwt method here, but you can alter it according to you, just remember to keep *constructor* and the logic of *canActivate* same.
Now in your *main.ts* modify global guard so we can use *Reflectors* in it:

```
const reflector = app.get(Reflector);
app.useGlobalGuards(new AuthGuard(reflector));
```

Now in order to make routes public we would use a custom decorator, for that create a file named *public.decorator.ts* and add the following code:

```
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';
export const Public = () => SetMetadata('isPublic', true);
```

Here we have added a custom metadata value which is same value that we used inside our *auth.guard.ts* file. Now just add this **@Public()** decorator on the route that you want to make public:

```
 @Get()
 @Public()
  async all() {
    //........
  }
```

Now your all function won't check for the token authentication.
I found [this](https://dev.to/dannypule/exclude-route-from-nest-js-authgaurd-h0) blog which does the same thing, you can check it out.

Comment: This approach is also in the official NestJS docs https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#enable-authentication-globally

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to change Guards to routes:

```
@ApiBearerAuth()
@ApiTags('books')
@Controller('books')
export class BooksController {

  @Post()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  async create(@Body() createBookVm: CreateBookVm) {
    //........
  }

  @Get()
  async all() {
    //........
  }
}
```

Comment: Not ideal solution as you need to migrate all functions to this format.

Answer (score 2):

To provide another answer, albeit one that requires more code, is you could create a custom decorator that assigns metadata to the class and/or the class method. This metadata, in theory, would be for telling the guard to skip the auth check on this entire class, or on this route (depending on how you set the metadata up), and return `true` so that the request can still flow.

I've got a decorator like this [set up here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma/blob/1e35310dcc4f123e6768983779f009340bb9d96e/packages/nestjs-module/src/decorators/skip.decorator.ts) that sets up metadata if you'd like to take a look at how it works.

With this kind of approach, you could bind the guard globally, and then add the `@AuthSkip()` (or whatever you call it) decorator to the routes or classes you don't want to authorize.

Now you'll need to extend the `AuthGuard('jwt')` and update the `canActivate()` method to check for this metadata in the current context. This means that you'll need to add the `Reflector` as a dependency to the guard class and use it to get the metadata from both the class and the current route (if you went so far as to make it work for ignoring classes and not just routes), and if the metadata exists, then the route was to be skipped, return `true` from the guard. [I make that kind of check here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma/blob/1e35310dcc4f123e6768983779f009340bb9d96e/packages/nestjs-module/src/interceptor/ogma.interceptor.ts#L67) if you'd like to see an example of that in action.